# nodejs mssql syntax error

Tags: sql-server, node.js

When I use the following query with the node-mssql module it gives an error stating that there is an

```
Invalid column name 'L'.
```

For some reason, it thinks the value within the like statement is a column name.

```
'SELECT TOP 10 * From [Products] WHERE [Code] LIKE "%LO%"
```

Is there some sort of special syntax I need to use

FULL CODE (from mssql npm example):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: '192.168.0.165\\database', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance 
        database: 'Products',

        options: {
            encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
        }
    }

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select TOP 10 * From [Products] WHERE [Code] LIKE "%LO%"', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)
                var items = [];
                recordset.forEach(function(row){
                    items.push(row.Code);
                })

            res.send(items);

        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Comment: show the full code+sql. you're obviously missing at least one `'` in there...

Comment: Are those double quotes around the search string? If so, you need 2 single quotes around it and another single quote to terminate the statement. But yes, showing more is better for all of us.

Comment: Code updated. I seem to have fixed it by using the statement below:
'select TOP 10 * From [Products] WHERE [Code] LIKE \'%lo%\''

Since I had to switch to single quotes and then escape the two used for the search string... Are double quotes illegal in mssql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using single quotes within a sql statement you must escape the ' character.

For example:

```
'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Products] WHERE [Code] LIKE \'%LO%\''
```